# Match part of a url using regular expression only

Tags: regex

Match below url to a regular expression:

```
https://api.com.org.net/abc/def/some_number/?key=value&key=value
```

match url with /abc/def in the url. Below is the regular expression I've tried and not working.

```
https:\/\/(<api\.com\.org\.net\/abc\/def>*)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `<` and `>`? They have no special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: They are named capturing group, I assume regex101 syntax. regex101.com, I am creating regular expression using that website.

Comment: Named capturing groups originate with .NET-style regular expressions.

Comment: @Vipul The syntax for named capturing groups is `(?<url>.*)` and the name part (url) must only consist of 'word' characters, i.e. `[A-Za-z0-9_]` typically. You can't write your expression in the name part, the syntax would be `https:\/\/(?<url>api\.com\.org\.net\/abc\/def.*)` in your example.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
(?:[\w:.\/]+)\/abc\/def
```

See the demo here: https://regexr.com/50sva

Comment: I need exact match of /abc/def instead of anything that is matched.